# How to build multiple large scale fish tanks with water at different temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, concrete, heating-systems, water-resources

I am wondering at a high level what are the *material components* that might be used in building several large scale fish tanks that are *temperature regulated* like on a fishing farm.

For example, what I am imagining is something like this:

```
 __________________________________________________
|                |                |                |
|     Tank 1     |    Tank 2      |       3        |
|                |                |                |
|________________|________________|________________|
|                |                |                |
|                |                |                |
|       4        |       5        |      6         |
|                |                |                |
|________________|________________|________________|
|                |                |                |
|                |                |                |
|       7        |       8        |      ...       |
|                |                |                |
|                |                |                |
|________________|________________|________________|
```

Where each tank is let's say 10 meters by 10 meters. There could be potentially a hundred or more of these tanks.

The reason for the many tanks are twofold:

1. To separate certain species of fish from one another.
2. To create different environments (salinity, nutrients, and most relevant, **temperature**).

The question is *how you would keep these tanks at a certain temperature*. Perhaps, let's say, they are indoor. Or if it can be answered both ways, then including outdoor would be interesting to know but I imagine there are too many additional constraints in that case. So let's say they are indoor.

*I am not an engineer, I do software development, but I am  interested in learning how to build real stuff too.*

I would imagine that these are built with concrete, then somehow perhaps the concrete is heated or cooled with some technology. Or perhaps instead of regulating the temperature of the concrete, the water is cooled somehow directly. I would like to know how this cooling process would work, so I can understand how something like this could be built. Right now I can imagine the structural components for the most part (reinforced concrete, for example, and digging the dirt, etc.), but I don't know how the actual *temperature regulation* would work at this scale. Also would be interested to know (if there are multiple ways), what the best vs. the most cost effective way would be (or just if this type of thing is considered expensive or not). But if that's too much to ask, just knowing generally how you would implement this sort of thing would be the main question.

Comment: Each tank will need its own circulation pump, heater and supply.

Comment: This will likely be closed as too broad.

Comment: You could do it using a square tank with a submerged pump inside which "blows" water from the tank to the tank itself to create a good homogenisation of the temperature in tank. (Try IRL with some fish to determine how well they're able or not to behave). Then to regulate the temperature (cooling and heating) you could use a heat pump regulated with a PID minimising the difference between the setpoint temperature and the temperature measured in the tank. If only heating is required you could simply use the same technology as an electric kettle and regulate the temperature with a PID as well.